# what unsigned char data[0]; means

Tags: c

I found this line defined in a structure in a C source code

```
unsigned char data[0];
```

Is it a buffer with unlimeted length? is it supported in the C89 or only in C99?

Comment: It's a hack for variable-sized structures. And indeed a duplicate - at least 3 such questions have been asked already.

Comment: You put it at the end of a structure with an unknown size, and then you can allocate instances of that structure with different sizes, and use this field (`data`) in order to access the additional piece of memory that has been allocated to each instance.